# Merge neighbouring cells in table columns dynamically with JavaScript - fix bug

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, merge

I'm trying to merge cells which have the same values as their vertical neighbours (Credit to user:179125 for your help).

If you run this snippet, you'll see that this works for the first column (i.e. the 3 fish cells merge with each other and the 2 bird cells merge with each other) but not the second column (the two salmon cells don't merge) and at this point a type error occurs. Note that no error occurs when running this without the for loop and just for a single column. Please can someone shed some light on why this isn't working for me? Thanks very much!

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

for (let i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
  let headerCell = null;

  for (let row of table.rows) {
    const firstCell = row.cells[i];

    if (headerCell === null || firstCell.innerText !== headerCell.innerText) {
      headerCell = firstCell;
    } else {
      headerCell.rowSpan++;
      firstCell.remove();
    };
  };
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>plaice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>robin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>crow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: just a quick check - If there are no rows then ```firstCell = row.cells[i]``` will be undefined and you will get the TypeError.  You can debug and print firstCell and see what happen after a row with "crow" is trying to get processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when in the first column cells are deleted, that row will have fewer cells than before and so any subsequent reference to `row.cells[i]` will not be the *original* i<sup>th</sup> cell, as it will not count the deleted cells. Therefore such a reference can be wrong (in another column than intended) or even out of range (which is what you get in your example).

You can avoid this by making the outer loop start from the right column, going back to the first:

```
for (let i = table.rows[0].cells.length; i--;) {
```

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

for (let i = table.rows[0].cells.length; i--;) {
  let headerCell = null;

  for (let row of table.rows) {
    const firstCell = row.cells[i];

    if (headerCell === null || firstCell.innerText !== headerCell.innerText) {
      headerCell = firstCell;
    } else {
      headerCell.rowSpan++;
      firstCell.remove();
    };
  };
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>plaice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>robin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>crow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that's a good point. Unfortunately this approach also seems to run into issues... https://jsbin.com/pigoqodici/edit?html,css,js,console,output Can you think of a solution to this?

Comment: Thanks trincot. Unfortunately the code which you sent me seems to have a syntax error: https://jsbin.com/vigociwope/edit?console  -  please do let me know if I’m confused here or if this wasn’t exactly what you meant.

Comment: I don't see any syntax error? Console panel is empty when I run it there. What is the error you see? This is valid JS.

Comment: I added a snippet to my answer where I just used that `for` line, and it runs fine without errors. I don't understand which problem you are bumping into. What browser are you using?

Comment: Gosh - thanks, somehow I didn't see the full code snippet. This does indeed run without an error, and when I run it on a larger table it does produce the intended ouput. However, in the table in the example, instead of causing the 'salmon' row to have a rowspan of two, it seems to just delete one of the 'salmon' cells.

Comment: I'm also extremely confused about the fact that the for loop has only two arguments! How does it know when to stop looping? :) - Appreciate all your help on this.

Comment: As to the effect on "salmon": indeed, a cell with "salmon" is deleted, and if it were not that also in the first column a cell is deleted, you would have seen the "enlarged" effect of a merged cell. But, .... because also in the first column a cell is  deleted/merged, the rendering has no more reason to stretch these two cells vertically more than necessary, and so it looks like one row from the original was deleted. This is just how HTML rendering works.

Comment: Concerning the `for` loop: the third part is empty (which normally would be `i++` or `i--`). This is because that change of `i` is put in the *condition* part of the `for` loop. This works nicely, because `i--` first evaluates `i` (if that is 0, the loop ends) and only then decrements it. This means the first iteration will be with `i = length-1` and the last iteration with `i = 0`. You could of course write `for (let i = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`, but that is just more text for ending up doing the same thing.